# redirecting from another page taking info

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So after the user signs up, i redirect them to my additional info page where i collect some more information. However, something is wrong with my design/implementation as rails is saying im missing users/create template

this is my users controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end


    def additional_info
      @user = User.new(user_addinfo)
      if @user.save
       redirect_to show_path
      end
    end


    def create
     @user = User.new(user_params)
     if @user.save
     # UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to  additional_info_path
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to InYourShoes!"
      #return @user  
     else
       render'new'
     end
  end  

    private

      def user_params 
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end


      def user_addinfo
        params.permit(:year)
      end
  end
```

def show is the user profile page i want to show after redirecting to the `additional_info` page

def `additional_info` is just take additional info from the private method def `user_addinfo`

def create is the sign up process.

After entering the basic user info, it gets redirected to additional which is fine. but after the additional, it says im missing the users/create template, but my code  i attempted to redirect to `show_path` and `#usersshow`, still doesnt work

any suggestions? sorry if this seems intuitive but Im new to rails.

Comment: what you're doing is not so clear, but i think that the problem is in your additional_info method, cause you're creating a brand new user with just the parameters in user_addinfo, without creating a session... what are you using to managing sessions for user authentication?

Comment: i have a sessions controller that handles that, i thuought the sign_in itsef is a session?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the additional_info method, as i said in the comment. What you're doing is:

- creating a user
- creating a session for the user (sign_in @user) - storing somewhere the user_id in the session
- redirecting to your additional_info page
  And here comes the problem. As the user is already signed in you don't have any need to create a new user with additional params. You should have some helper to retrieve the current signed in user (like current_user) and in additional_info method, just update it.

So your additional_info method would become something like:

```
def additional_info
  user = User.find session[:user_id]
  user.update params[:user]
  redirect_to user_path #show action
end
```

Comment: where should i define the helper? is it a method i should define in my session controller?

Comment: i'm sorry i wrote wrong i'm going to edit my answer. no need for an helper

Comment: getting this error
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#additional_info
Couldn't find User without an ID

fromt this line:
user = User.find session[:user_id]

Comment: it means that you are not storing the user_id in the session. In your create method, or better inside your sign_in method, you can do something like
`session[:user_id] = @user.id`
with whatever variable you're using

Comment: sorry for being so clueless, i'm new to rails and i looked at my files and found that my sign_in method is in a module sessionsHelper
instead of storing id..... its using remember_tokens....
i followed the rails tutorial by michael hartl if that helps

Comment: no problem. you can do the same in the create method, before redirecting. 
`if @user.save
session[:user_id] = @user.id`

Comment: its saying user.update user_add_info_params is  a undefinded local variable or method???

Comment: instead of using your private method (that you should modify to 
`def user_addinfo
        params.require(:user).permit(:year)
      end`)
you can use the additional params in the form of the additional page (i guess is only the year). something like
`@user.update params[:user]`
but you have to check how the form in the additional page info is done, cause i'm just guessing.

Comment: form in the additional page is done by a f.textfield input
If i make user_addinfo public it would work right? but that defeats the purpose of hiding data correct?

Comment: no you don't have to make it public, it has to stay private. Just correct it adding the require. about the form you have to look in your log how it is sending the parameters, and the grab them to update your user.

Comment: sorry what log are you talking about?

Comment: don't you have a terminal opened with the server log? where you run rails server? that is the log

Comment: oh yeah on the terminal, im still trying to figure out the saving session part